# Itemize - set default option

Tags: lists, itemize, optional-arguments

I have plenty of lists, all with the `[noitemsep]` option:

```
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item foo
    \item bar
\end{itemize}
```

Is it possible, to setup itemize to use this option by default? Or do I have to write my own "wrapper" macro around `itemize`.

Comment: [Which package provides `[noitemsep]`?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to redefine the list default settings with `enumitem`. You can use a global option or limit the scope to the environment you want to use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: nice, works for `enumerate` as well

Answer (score 0):

I personally only use `enumitem` in case there's no other way to do something. You could use the [`paralist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paralist) package instead and use the `compactitem` environment.

Comment: What's the problem with `enumitem`?

Comment: @T.Verron Simple things require a rather complicated syntax. With `paralist` you just say what your first item should look like and the package does the rest for you. It has its limits but you don't get all the complexity of being able to define your lists any way you want either.

Comment: `paralist`s `compactitem` environment also removes the spaces before and after the list -- it resembles `enumitem`s `nolistsep` option rather than `noitemsep`.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own environment:

```
\newenvironment{newitemize}{\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]}{\end{itemize}}
```

should do.

Comment: It seems the OP wanted to avoid wrapper environments if possible.